# Sending CMD commands to a sleeping pc

Tags: c#, cmd, sleep-mode

I am working on a little project for my internship and I have run into a slight problem.

I am developing a system which would automatically turn on a TV screen in the cantine of the company once people enter the room. For this I am using an Arduino, a PIR sensor, an IR led (to turn the screen on and off) and a Digital Engine DE6140 (which is a mini PC that will play the content on the screen).

Here is my question:

I want to put both the screen and the PC to sleep once there is no one in the room. This is easy with the TV since it's just IR codes, but for the PC I'd have to use Rs-232. The Arduino would process the sensor's data and technically I would be able to send that via RS-232 to the PC. I know you can then use this data in a code (C#) to put the screen to sleep, but how would I then wake the PC up? Is there a way to send CMD commands to the PC and/or program running on it once it's sleeping?

I really hope my question is clear enough and I hope even more that you guys can help me. If anything is unclear, just ask me. :)

The PC is using windows 7 embedded, by the way.

Comment: What about [wake on lan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)? It is an standard protocol, supported for many operative systems, and you have [MS sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sending-the-Wake-on-Lan-in-696884ac/sourcecode?fileId=158887&pathId=738352787)

Comment: I guess that could work, but i'd have to get a lan port for my arduino then. I am really trying to keep this as simple and cost efficient as possible.

Comment: An stanby computer would wake on new input (keyboard/mouse) or network card specific commands (wake on lan). I may be wrong, but I dont think is other way.

Comment: Only RS232 related thing I have found is this, no clue about how to implement it tho. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-ring

Comment: Interesting link maybe: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=15656.0, Is there any way to connect to the PC via something else than RS232? I mean through my googling, if you cannot afford additionnal hardware, they all talk about USB/PS2 connection to wake up the PC, through keyboard emulation for example. Don't know if it's possible at all in your case...

Comment: This recent article from Microsoft does not mention serial communications ports as an option. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-wake-sources

Comment: I've looked into wake on ring and I have tried to figure out if that would work. It seems like my device doesn't support wake on ring. Sadly wake on Lan is no option either. 

I have decided to use windows task planner instead, It doesn't give me the full result I want, but at least it puts it to sleep at night.

Thank you all for your reactions